# Unity (photon/networking): how to move object that was instantiated by other player?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Keeping my Photon project under given 500 msg/s is really tricky. Even with 10 players in room each updating position 10 times per second 10(players) * 10(sent msg) * 10(received msg) = 1000 msg/s is generated. That is just the player movement. Next I need to move bullets around which will increase the amount of messages once more.

At the moment I have bullets instantiated across network but only local player is able to move it since I don't yet sync movement of bullets. I was wondering could I have all of the clients start moving the bullets on their local device once it's instantiated instead of passing position through network? This would save a lot of messages since I would never have to send bullet positions over network.

Hacking and cheating is not a problem in my game.

EDIT: this is the script I'm using at the moment to move bullets. This only works locally on the device that bullet was instantiated on. How would I run this script locally on each client?

```c#
public class Network_Bullet : Photon.MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    [HideInInspector]
    public float speed = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector2 direction = Vector2.zero;

    public void SetValues(float _speed, Vector2 _direction)
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

        this.speed = _speed + 150f; // bullet has 150 more speed than player
        this.direction = _direction;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (speed != 0) 
        {
            rb.velocity = direction * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is how to bullet is instantiated:

```c#
private void OnClick_Shoot()
    {
        if (photonView.isMine == true) 
        {
            if (timeSinceLastBullet >= spawnTime) 
            {
                GameObject newBullet = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate (Path.Combine ("prefabs", "Network Bullet"), transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
                newBullet.GetComponent<Network_Bullet> ().SetValues (owner.speed, new Vector2(owner.last_horizontal, owner.last_vertical));

                timeSinceLastBullet = 0f;
            } 
            else 
            {
                Debug.Log ("loading...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, 10 players with 10 movement messages per second generates 100 messages per second per room.
To the actual question - for bullets, all you need to do is instantiate and give it initial rotation and speed. Because bullets usually don't change their rotation or speed (at least in video games), you only need to do that and only update the bullets in everyone's local machines.

Comment: Hello, I updated my question with code example. How would I run the code on all the clients instead of just on device bullet was instantiated?

Comment: Also is receiving data not counted as messages? How I've been counting messages is that local player sends 10 msg/s and receives 90 msg/s (from other 9 players). This would add up to 100 msg/s but thats only for one player. Multiply that with number of players it would add up to 1000 msg/s per room.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```c#
private void OnClick_Shoot()
{
    if (timeSinceLastBullet >= spawnTime) 
    {
        int level = 2; //it is not need for you, but you can setup some params on object
        // for example i set level for increase damage per level.
        string someMsg = "hi i'm bullet";
        object[] parametres = new object[] {
           level,
           someMsg
        }
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate (Path.Combine ("prefabs", "Network Bullet"), transform.position, transform.rotation, 0, parametres );

        timeSinceLastBullet = 0f;
    } 
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log ("loading...");
    }
}
```

And bullet, just add PhotonView component on your prefab and it will be work

```c#
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

   private Rigidbody2D rb;

   [HideInInspector]
   public float speed = 0;
   [HideInInspector]
   public Vector3 direction = Vector3.zero;

   void Start()
   {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

       this.speed = _speed + 150f; // bullet has 150 more speed than player
       this.direction = _direction;

       PhotonView pView = gameObject.GetPhotonView();
       // or
       //PhotonView pView = gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();

       damage = 10 * pView[0]; // increase damage per level
       Debug.Log(pView[1]);

   }

   void Update()
   {
       if (speed != 0) 
       {
           rb.velocity = direction * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
       }
   }
}
```

So, that methods will be work localy on all clients. I'm using that on my bullets.